# std::map emplace with key obtained during value construction

Tags: stdmap, emplace

Suppose we have a map of some complex objects, textures in my case.

`std::map<unsigned int, Texture> _table;`

What would be the most correct way to insert an object into such a map with a key which is obtained during the value (Texture) construction?

Say, we have:

```
Texture::Texture() { glGenTextures(1, &_id); }
Texture::~Texture() { glDeleteTextures(1, &_id); }
```

`glGenTextures()` provides a new OpenGL ID into the `_id`class data member.
`glDeleteTextures()` releases resources and invalidates `_id`.
So, I would like to avoid any intermediate objects and copying.

And after that I want to store this newly constructed texture in my _table.

```
Texture tex;
_table.insert({tex._id, tex});
```

I would prefer to use emplace here, but I'm not sure it is possible/safe to construct the texture and get the `_id` to use for map insertion in the same line.

As for me, this looks like a pattern which should probably exist.

Otherwise, why should I not do anything like that?

Comment: Before you do anything else you should ensure your `Texture` class cannot be copied. If that's not possible then the RHS of your map could use smart pointers to `Texture`.

Comment: Thank you, @RichardNixon. Sure, while playing around with this problem, I have explicitly defined the copy constructor and operator= and explicitly deleted the move constructor and operator=.